# existence of a solution in a homeomorphic region to a disk

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I'm trying to solve this exercise from Sotomayor's EDO book. My idea to solve it is through homotopic functions, trying to find a general way to deform the first function into the second through any arbitrary point. however, I have not succeeded. any suggestion is welcome

let  $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R $  be a continuous function, suppose there are two solutions ($\phi , \psi $) of $ x^\prime$ =$f(t,x)$ satisfying , $Graf (\phi)\cap Graf(\psi)=\{(0,p), (1,q)\}$
y  $Graf (\phi)\cup Graf(\psi)$ = Border of a  homeomorphic D region to a disk, then , for all $x\in D$ there is a solution $ h $, of  $x^\prime$ =$f(t,x)$ such that your graph contains $(0,p) , (1,q) , x $

Comment: What's $Graf$? ${}{}$

Comment: is the graph of the function